# Given an array find all the pairs with product between a given range

Tags: algorithm

Given an array having n elements, find all the possible pairs of elements whose product is between `x` and `y` provided by the user, i.e. all `i` and `j` less than `n`, s.t. `x <= a[i] * a[j] <= y`.

A naive approach is to use two nested loops and check if the product lies in the given range increase the count. The time complexity of this approach will be `n^2`.

How can we do better?

Comment: You could sort the array and do a binary search, finding an element between `x` and `y`, then checking the values before and after the found element. The time complexity would be `O(n log n)` for a quick sort (or merge), `O(log n)` for a binary search and `O(n)` for finding the other elements in the worst case (if all the elemets are between `x` and `y`).

Comment: The size of the output is O(n^2) in the worst case (for example, products of all pairs could be in the range), so you cannot do any better than that.